# C# - Rendering a partial in a ternary operator

Tags: c#, asp.net, partial-views, conditional-operator

I'm conditionally rendering a footer using a ternary operator. I was doing `@RenderPage`, and even though it worked it meant having a controller as well as some other extra code.

I'm running into a `; expected` error, and according to StackOverflow and some documentation it's a generic error and could be caused by a number of different things.

Is my syntax correct? Or is there something I'm missing?

---

```
// in this section is a switch statement that sets isNewFooter to true or false depending on which page has loaded.

 <div class="body-content">
    @RenderBody()

    @{
       (isNewFooter ? Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/NewFooter.cshtml") : Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/OldFooter.cshtml"))
     }

</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ternary operators are used to evaluate different *expressions*, not to execute different *statements*. You can just use a standard `if`:

```
if (isNewFooter) 
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/NewFooter.cshtml"); 
else
    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/OldFooter.cshtml");
```

or, refactor out the common stuff so you *can* use a ternary operator:

```
Html.RenderPartial(String.Format("~/Views/Shared/{0}Footer.cshtml", (isNewFooter ? "New" : "Old")));
```

Use whichever of those is easier for you to read and maintain.

Comment: Hey @DStanley, thanks for the info. I didn't know that ternary operators behaved that way. The `;` error persisted with the second option so I went with the first one, and it's now up and running.

Comment: @Bodrov I left out the semicolons in both cases. Both should work with that fixed.